# How to use own image as a base map in python

Tags: python, gis

I have prepared code for generating South pole grid for Moon. I am facing difficulty in using own tiff image as a baseman for same grid (Moon south Polar region). Further I have many tiff images which I want to oveon basemap image.

How can I proceed further in python?

The code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# setup south polar stereographic basemap.
m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=0,lon_0=360,resolution='l')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(0.,-90.,20.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,20.))
plt.title("South Polar Stereographic Projection")
plt.show()
```

The image which i want used for base map is available on [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AUSQX2LVBtdLVBW_CXgNApkROgFWsjKN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.